# how to get GoStructType object by GoFunctionDeclaration. idea plugin for goland

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, goland

```
type SiteInfo struct {
    id int64
}

type SiteResult struct {
    id int64
}

func test(info *SiteInfo) *SiteResult{
    return nil
}
```

I want to get param & return struct (May be GoStructType.class). to get all fields.

eg: to get all fields for SiteInfo.

part of the code

```
public class TransformAction extends AnAction {

    private Project project;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent e) {

        // offset is current offset
        PsiElement psiElement = PsiUtilCore.getElementAtOffset(psiFile, offset);
        GoFunctionDeclaration func = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(psiElement, GoFunctionDeclaration.class);
        GoSignature signature = func.getSignature();
        signature.getResultType();// how to get GoStructType.class
        signature.getParameters(); // how to get GoStructType.class

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is

`GoTypeUtil.findTypeSpec(signature.getResultType(), signature, true).getSpecType().getType()`

Long answer is that `signature.getResultType()` gets you `GoPointerType` which is a pointer to a type reference (not type itself). You need to unwrap and resolve it.

1. Unwrap pointer and get its base type reference
   `GoType typeRef =((GoPointerType)signature.getResultType()).getType()`
2. Resolve type reference
   `GoTypeSpec typeSpec = (GoTypeSpec)typeRef.resolve(signature);`
3. Get the type from the type spec
   `GoStructType structType = (GoStructType)typeSpec.getSpecType().getType();`

The same goes for parameters

```
for (GoParamDefinition paramDef : signature.getParameters().getDefinitionList()) {
  GoType paramType = paramDef.getGoType(null);
  GoStructType structType = (GoStructType)GoTypeUtil.findTypeSpec(paramType, signature, true).getSpecType().getType();
}
```

Also it is possible to get [underlying type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types) of a pointer base type which in your case will return the same result:

```
GoStructType structType = (GoStructType)GoTypeUtil.unwrapPointerAndParTypes(signature.getResultType())
  .getUnderlyingType(signature)
```

Comment: Thanks again, with your help. I finished my idea plugin.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22196-struct-to-struct